# Foreach in a foreach? show uncorrect data

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have 2 table. `t1` and `t2`.

`t1` data as below:

```
+--------+---------------+--------------+
| mid    | name          | desc         |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1      | Fris          | Helo         |
| 2      | Kenn          | Wow!         |
| 3      | Henny         | CCC          |
+---------------------------------------+
```

`t2` data as below:

```
+--------+---------+----------------+
| tid    | mid     | tcode          |
+-----------------------------------+
| 1      | 1       | 1              |
| 2      | 1       | GG             |
| 3      | 1       | TTTTTT!        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Now my php coding is like this:

```
$xzdtall = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY mid ASC");
foreach($xzdtall as $xzdt){
    $testing = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE mid = $xzdt['mid'] ORDER BY tid ASC");
    foreach($testing as $test){
        $testlist[] = $test;
    }
    $xzdtlist[] = $xzdt;
}
```

And now my looping as below:

```
#my looping
<!--{loop $xzdtlist $xzdt}-->
<div>$xzdt[name] <!--{loop $testlist $test}--><b>$test[tcode]</b><!--{/loop}--></div>
<!--{/loop}-->
```

My final output:

```
<div>Fris <b>1</b><b>GG</b><b>TTTTTT!</b></div>
<div>Kenn <b>1</b><b>GG</b><b>TTTTTT!</b></div>
<div>Henny <b>1</b><b>GG</b><b>TTTTTT!</b></div>
```

And actually I need it be like this since `Kenn`'s AND `Henny`'s `mid` does not inside t2:

```
<div>Fris <b>1</b><b>GG</b><b>TTTTTT!</b></div>
<div>Kenn</div>
<div>Henny</div>
```

Comment: Despite your question being  unclear, I would guess, you need to clear `testlist` before the inner loop, e.g. `testlist = array();`

Comment: You also should mention the DB and template library, you're using. This might make it easier to read and interpret the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$testlist` variable has different values for every `$xzdt`, so you loop should be:

```
$xzdtall = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY mid ASC");
foreach ($xzdtall as $xzdt){
    // empty $testlist
    $testlist = array();
    $testing = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE mid = $xzdt['mid'] ORDER BY tid ASC");
    foreach($testing as $test){
        $testlist[] = $test;
    }

    // add `$testlist` to $xzdt
    $xzdt['t2s'] = $testlist;

    $xzdtlist[] = $xzdt;
}
```

Then in your template (don't know what engine it is) something like that should work:

```
<!--{loop $xzdtlist $xzdt}-->
<div>$xzdt[name] <!--{loop $xzdt[t2s] $test}--><b>$test[tcode]</b><!--{/loop}--></div>
                                 ^ notice variable here
<!--{/loop}-->
```

Also you can test if `$xzdt[t2s]` is not empty.

In the end, I advise you to learn about mysql `JOIN`s and replace your cyclic queries with a single query with `JOIN`.

Comment: yes, this works!
I have try Inner Join or left join, but also duplicate the data, so I come here to find help..

Comment: Hi, just now I try and find out a problem.

Comment: Your code should work. Test again, Output `$xdztlist`, see what's there.